# Can't edit media details in new role

Tags: media, media-library, permissions

I've created a new user role called "writer" and assigned him the following capabilities.

```
read, 
edit_post ,
upload_files, 
edit_posts, 
edit_published_posts,
publish_posts,
level_0,
level_1,
level_2`
```

The user can upload images but cannot edit the media details like title, caption etc.
[image: non editable media file details]

The text boxes are read only. Am I missing a permission in the user role?

Edit: 
the code for the role is:

```
add_role( 'writer', 'Writer', array(
    'read'=>true,
    'edit_post'=>true,
    'upload_files'=>true,
    'edit_posts'=>true,
    'edit_published_posts'=> true,
    'publish_posts'=>true,
    'level_0'=>true,
    'level_1'=>true,
    'level_2'=>true
    )
 );
```

Edit: Found it.
Somehow adding the capability "edit_others_posts" fixed the issue.

Comment: Please could you add the complete code of the function for this role so we can see where maybe some went wrong?

Comment: @Charles added the code as requested.

Comment: First some minor notes: be consequent when coding. Meaning by that, do not use single and/or double quote mix in your code as shown *(and done by you)*. Secondly what are those level_* do in the code, what are they meant for? Third did you check the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)?

Comment: @Charles. The inconsistency was due to debugging and adding different capabilities and will be corrected. The level_* was experimentally added in the end after reviewing the level of 'author' from the codex who is allowed to edit media details. I got it using the code `$role = get_role('author');foreach( $role->capabilities as $name => $val ){echo $name . "<br />";}` . I did check the codex, but couldn't find anything on media description editing

Comment: Found it.
Somehow adding the capability "edit_others_posts" fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice?! but there must be somewhere a culprit. There is NO need for that role to do/allow that, as long you don't want that role also editing other users posts/media/comments. Btw that user role does not allow to delete them I hope you are aware of that. I added an answer which allows that writer to 1: add/edit an upload and 2: delete the upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment(s), below the code as it imho should be.*(tested and working)*

```
/**
 * Add new role: Writer
 * This role allows to: Add/Edit/Delete Posts and Uploads
 *
 * Read more: {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities}
 *
 * Works with @version WP4.8.1 and below
 */
add_role( 'writer', 'Writer', 
    array( 
        'delete_posts'           => true,
        'delete_published_posts' => true,
        'edit_posts'             => true,
        'edit_published_posts'   => true,
        'publish_posts'          => true,
        'read'                   => true,
        'upload_files'           => true, 
        )
    );
```

> Add the code in `functions.php` and please remove it after it is added/visible in the Back-end(Admin panel) because it will be add to your database. Else WP will try to add the role *(although already done)* **every** visit from every user all the time. *(Useless and a bad habit in this case)*

Just as note, please read the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) so you understand what I tried to explain.
 Adjust *(delete unneeded code)* to your own preferences.